# How to use SKTestSession in UI tests? Xcode 12 GM

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, storekit, xcode12

I added `SKTestSession` in my UI tests and it loads my `.storekit` file ok, at least that's what it says. But my store related code cannot be tested because `SKProductsRequest` never succeeds nor fails. Looks like it doesn't work at all. I use Xcode 12 GM atm.

Here's my code in UI tests' `setUpWithError()`:

```
if session == nil {
    do {
        session = try SKTestSession(configurationFileNamed: "StoreConfiguration")
    } catch (let e) {
        print("Error: \(e)")
    }
}
```

Where `session` is a varin my test class.

When I just run project with `.storekit` set up in scheme it works just OK. But fails when it comes to UI tests.

So, how to make `SKTestSession` work in my UI tests?

Comment: What does "never succeeds nor fails. Looks like it doesn't work at all" mean?

Comment: This means that request starts but never calls it's delegate methods. Thanks, will upd the post.

Comment: Well, you have not shown code for "request starts" or "delegate methods" so it's hard to assess what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Double checked and found that I never implemented the `request:didFailWithError:` method! And it is called now with a strange error which I will ask about in the another question.

Comment: I've discovered that StoreKit testing works only when building unit and UI tests with Debug configuration and refuses to work when building with Release or Profile configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad: I never implemented `SKProductsRequestDelegate`'s method `request:didFailWithError:` so I got no error. Now I get the error and gonna post another question about it.